# Solution for Approval Token before big transaction?

Tags: laravel, token

As the title says. This is the condition I have.

I wanted to make approval token before a user can do certain things. Here's my situation :

1. I have a web application made with Laravel 5.1
2. All user are already authenticated before they can use the web app
3. Before the user do any large transaction, the User needs approval from supervisor and in some case the director (software side). This is a preventive measure against fraud and employee stealing money.

Now I've been looking at a few solution but all that I've found are to further authenticate user when they login. I'm not sure I can modify it to do what I want.

Here are some of the solution I've been reading :

1. google 2fa
2. authy

This is the workflow I imagine to fulfill my need :

1. The user opens the web application and authenticate using their credential
2. The user navigate to a certain page and do a large transaction.
3. Before they press the "submit" button, the supervisor or the director must enter some kind of token (One Time Password perhaps) before the submit buttons activate.
4. On the server side, the application process all the inputs and authenticate the token (one time password), if the token (one time password) checks out, everything runs.

Can anyone gives me suggestion about the workflow? and Is there any solution to fulfill the needs?

I'm open to any suggestion.

Thank you very much.

*disclaimer : Sorry if the grammar is wrong or somethings are confusing, english is my 3rd language.

Comment: Your workflow could work. You have to think of a way to generate the "one-time password" every time for the supervisor. Why not just use the same password all the time? Another option would be to have an email sent to the supervisor with a temporary link to approve

Comment: Not the same password because if the supervisor is not onsite, the user must still be able to do the transaction in a timely manner (quickly). well the email thing could work. I'll put it into consideration. Thank you

Comment: If supervisor have access to email (with smart phone for exemple) they would get a notification each time someone wants to do a big transaction and they would only have to press on "accept" or "deny" link. It would be quite easy to implement in Laravel